# Virtual environments for Python based Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am looking at [Microsoft's recommended folder structure for Python Based Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure) which contains some shared code and two functions in one app, along with testing. I have tried to implement this using VSCode but I am struggling to understand how this project structure works with Python's virtual environments.

If I was not publishing Functions (i.e. just starting with a basic Python library with unit testing), I would create a virtual environment at the same level as `test` so that my older structure may look something like

```
__app__
 | 
 .venv
 |
 | - shared_code
 | | - my_first_helper_function.py
 | | - my_second_helper_function.py
 |
 tests
```

When I create `my_first_function` using VSCode (turning `__app__` into an Azure Function project), VSCode Azure Function Extension creates a new virtual environment at the same level as `my_first_function` so the folder structure then looks like

```
__app__
 | 
 .venv
 | 
 | - .venv
 | |
 | - my_first_function
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | | - example.py
 | - shared_code
 | | - my_first_helper_function.py
 | | - my_second_helper_function.py
 |
 tests
```

i.e. the project contains multiple virtual environments. If I remove the new venv (the one at the same levels as `my_first_function`), I cannot deploy the Function correctly (the Function fails because it can't find the modules in the venv). If I delete the original venv, I cannot get the tests to run.

Is this an issue with the VSCode Functions Extension? How should I set up the virtual environments to ensure I can have unit testing (not deployed to Azure) with common code and two Azure Functions?

Any pointer greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/469#issuecomment-645164001) comment, I was able to delete the virtual environment created by the Azure Functions Extension (but needed to leave `requirements.txt` so that clearly needs to be correct), modify the following two lines in in `settings.json`

```
"azureFunctions.pythonVenv": "..\\.venv",
"azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "__app__"
```

and add `options` objects in `tasks.json` so that the full file looks as follows

```
 "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "pipInstall",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\${config:azureFunctions.deploySubpath}"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "pipInstall",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}\\${config:azureFunctions.deploySubpath}"
            }
        }
    ]
```

As a final note, not made explicit in the documentation, if I wanted to maintain a directory structure inside `tests` and get VSCode to discover these, I needed to add empty `__init__.py` files to each testing folder. These files are not needed in the 'library' if the version of Python 3 is new enough (post 3.3 I think)

Comment: Yes. `__init__.py` lets the interpreter know the parent is a package. Python 3.3+ introduced implicit namespace packages, hence this is no longer required.